# Get Value From ComboBox that uses external items C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, get, external

So I am creating a program which has several comboboxes for a user to select an option from. My aim was to populate the comboboxes from an API I have created, which I have succeeded with. I have used an Enum in my API containing everything I want to appear in my ComboBox.

Now, I'm wanting to put all my data from my comboboxes and text boxes, into an array.

I cannot seem to get the selected item of the comboboxes! I have tried:

```
String s = comboBox1.Text;
```

but '.Text' is not an option for me to use and neither is '.SelectedItem'

What should I use?
Thank you!

Comment: Why won't you use `.Text`?

Answer (score 0):

SelectedValue should work

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="comboBox1" Margin="0,0,0,64">
            <ComboBox.Items>
                <sys:String>a</sys:String>
                <sys:String>b</sys:String>
                <sys:String>c</sys:String>
                <sys:String>d</sys:String>
                <sys:String>e</sys:String>
            </ComboBox.Items>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="10,0,10,22" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=comboBox1}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a SelectionChanged event, then in code:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
   string value = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```